# Typescript keyof of a certain type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something like so, where I want to have a an idKey which is a keyof T but only the properties of type number.

Is this possible?

```
export const updateList = <T>(
  idKey: keyof T extends number,
  list: T[],
  id: number
) => {
  const listItem = list.find(x => x[idKey] === id)
}
```

Having extends number is not right as gives an error, leaving it off also gives an error of:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'number' have no overlap.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't constrain the keys to those that have number values, but by using a record of `number` values for the list elements, you can kind of achieve what you want: https://tsplay.dev/m0AYqW. I can turn it into an answer if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, yes I think this works for that I am after.  If you could create this into an answer and then give and details about what `PropertyKey` and `Record` are that would be amazing thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type system isn't strong enough to constrain `idKey` to keys for which `T` has a number value, but you can get around this by instead using a generic parameter `K` for the type of `idKey` and constraining the `list` elements to objects that have a number value for that key `K`.

```js
const updateList = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  idKey: K,
  list: Record<K, number>[],
  id: number
) => {
  const listItem = list.find(x => x[idKey] === id)
  // ..
}
```

The builtin type `PropertyKey` is equal to `string | number | symbol` (i.e. any valid property key type), and `Record<K, number>` (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) stands for `{[P in K]: number}`. Basically, the type signature enforces that the `list` parameter is assignable to an array of singleton objects with an `idKey` number property, which also allows passing an array of objects with additional properties, as long as `idKey` has a number value.

Calls to `updateList` will now only type check correctly:

```js
const list = [{a: 8, b: 'x'}]

updateList('a', list, 0)

updateList('b', list, 0) // Error
```

Note that since the key parameter is leading the type inference, the error will be on the `list` parameter rather than on `'b'`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwCYEMoFMAyBLaMC8MAPANIzoAeGYSEMACgE4gLqNQCeJ6HAfABQAoGDGxJuHAFwwSAGmEwANrijSASulCMkpWTDBwAtgCM2vANoBdeSLHSDJtoICUBXjADeC0JFjLoAJIYhgRKKgB0AGbYNPwUbjAU5mISlgT4hGLOCgD0OTDh4YIAvoKCPnj%20sITmHijSABx6xtIA5BStxZZliKgYOND8rSitelV6AAzZgr1oWCpDxqNh0JOueTAAoozMjIJAA)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, it is not the `idKey` itself that needs to be of type `number`, but rather the type `T[keyof T]` needs to extend type number. So what you want to do is to restrict the `T` type to types that have values of type `number`. Something like this should work.

```
export const updateList = <T extends { [key: PropertyKey]: number }>(
  idKey: keyof T,
  list: T[],
  id: number
) => {
  const listItem = list.find(x => x[idKey] === id)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK5gCYEMbAAyAlunALxwA8AKnKActqnAN5wDaA1sAJ4BccAApQIYYLF4BpPgF1ByDAFsARhLgBfAHwAKALAAoOHGLYZAuD14QAZnBoAaQ8YA2pGIJodZToyewKympQhgCUFFpszogoZG7oAJIEShRw8TAAdDbETDogEXAgHKbmshTklKahhhpAA)

**Update:**
[Oblosys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532368/13221230) is more flexible.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is good for what I need in regards to not showing an error.  However the intellisense still shows all fields regardless of if they are number fields or not.  Do you know if there is a way around this?